# Pivot column but keep ordering in new column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ['1','1','1','2','2','2'], 
              'time_visited': ['2012-01-01 00:00:00','2012-01-01 00:00:00','2012-01-01 00:00:00','2012-01-01 11:11:11','2012-01-01 11:11:11','2012-01-01 11:11:11'], 
             'url_link': ['google.com', 'google.com/news', 'google.com/news/cnn', 'youtube.com', 'youtube.com/search', 'youtube.com/search/catvideos']})

df
```

Which looks like this:

```
    user_id time_visited    url_link
0   1   2012-01-01 00:00:00 google.com
1   1   2012-01-01 00:00:00 google.com/news
2   1   2012-01-01 00:00:00 google.com/news/cnn
3   2   2012-01-01 11:11:11 youtube.com
4   2   2012-01-01 11:11:11 youtube.com/search
5   2   2012-01-01 11:11:11 youtube.com/search/catvideos
```

Is it possible to do the following two things in pandas

1. To pivot the data so that a new column is created for each url_link - so you would attain the following table, with a counter like 1 to say it was visited or a 0>:

> ```
> user_id time_visited       google.com google.com/news google.com/news/cnn youtube.com etc
> 1       2012-01-01 00:00:00  1        1                  1                  0            
> 2       2012-01-01 11:11:11  0        0                  0                  1
> ```

2. is it possible to create a column after this that maintains the ordering of which how the urls were visited? for example is it possible to have a column appended at the end of those above columns that looks like something like this:

> ```
> user_id visited_order
> 1       google.com, google.com/news, google.com/news/cnn
> 2       youtube.com, youtube.com/search, youtube.com/search/catvideos
> ```

I am fairly new to Pandas so was hoping for some pointers in the right direction i have tried using `picot()` and `pivot_table()` but am stuck at the moment.

I am essentially trying to get a user's data to be on one row instead of being in "long" format - I don't mind how many extra columns it produces - but if there is a better way to do it i am open!

thanks

Comment: for no.1 you can use a multi index - i.e `df['urlSort'] = df.sort_values('time_visited')['url_link'].factorize()[0]`;`pd.crosstab([df.user_id, df.time_visited],[df['url_link'],df['urlSort']])` if you sort the values of the data frame use `.agg(','.join)`

Comment: @jezrael this is not `agg.join` only - see my comment above

Comment: @Manakin this solved it: `df1.reset_index(col_level = 0)`